# How to cast hex value to WORD, DWORD or QWORD and store the result in a double variable?

Tags: c, casting, hex, dword

I'm trying to cast a signed hex number to WORD, DWORD and QWORD by this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) {

  printf("WORD=%d\n",  (int16_t) strtol("F123", NULL, 16));
  printf("DWORD=%d\n", (int32_t) strtol("FFFFF123", NULL, 16));
  printf("QWORD=%lld\n", (int64_t) strtol("FFFFFFFFFFFFF123", NULL, 16));

  return 0;
}
```

But it returns the following:

```
WORD=-3805
DWORD=2147483647
QWORD=2147483647
```

http://ideone.com/mqjldk

But why the DWORD and QWORD castings are not returning `-3805` too?

I mean: `0xFFFFF123` stored in a DWORD would contain `-3805` value in decimal, not `2147483647`

Expected output:

```
WORD=-3805
DWORD=-3805
QWORD=-3805
```

Do you have an bitwise alternative to do it?

Comment: For WORD and DWORD case you must use `"%d"` instead of `"%ld"`

Comment: *not working as expected?* What is the expected result?

Comment: I guess -3805 for whole printf...

Comment: I've edited the question. `0xFFFFF123` stored in a DWORD would contain `-3805` value in decimal, not `2147483647`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

0xFFFFF123 is out of the range of a long int if a long int have 32 bit, so strtol() return LONG_MAX (0x7FFFFFFF = 2147483647 in our case).

use strtoull() to convert a string to a unsigned integer with at least 64 bits, and allways check for errors before proceed.

For print a integer with a specified bit size, use something like this:

```
printf("foo=%"PRIu32"\n",(uint32_t) foo);
```

a better way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS  //we need that for PRI[u]8/16/32 format strings
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <errno.h>

void error_exit(void)
  {
    perror("ups");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

int main(void) 
  {
    unsigned long long temp;
    errno=0;
    temp = strtoull("FFFFF123", NULL, 16);
    if(errno)
      {
        error_exit();
      }
    printf("DWORD=%"PRId32"\n", (int32_t) temp );
    errno=0;
    temp = strtoull("FFFFFFFFFFFFF123", NULL, 16);
    if(errno)
      {
        error_exit();
      }
    printf("QWORD=%"PRId64"\n", (int64_t) temp );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
```

Comment: This does not explain why the second example isn't negative.

Comment: 0xFFFFF123 is a positive number, not a negative number.

Comment: Not as 32-bit it's not.

Comment: Yes and what happens when you cast that positive number, which is larger than 0x7FFFFFFF, and convert it to a `int32_t`? Anyway, all 3 examples in the question are nonsensical, for many different reasons.

Comment: 0xFFFFFFFF and -1 have the same bit representation on a 32 bit int, but strtol dont care about bit representation, if it would do, the decimal number 4294967295 must be read as -1 without an error. (on systems where a long is 32 bit long)

Answer (score 4):

`strtol` does not assume two's complement input. In order for it to treat something as negative, you must use a minus sign. For example `"-F123"`. This is the reason why the 2nd and 3rd line don't give negative output.

In case of the first line, you got the expected output mostly by accident. Because *after*  the `strtol` call, you casted the hex value `0xF123` down to `int16_t`. It will not fit inside a `int16_t`, so it gets converted to a negative value.

Some bugs:

- `strtol("FFFFFFFFFFFFF123")` will not work if `long` cannot hold the result. You should be using `strtoll`.
- To print the stdint.h types, use the format specifier `PRId` from inttypes.h, example: `printf("WORD=%" PRId16 "\n", my_int16_t);`
- Overall, avoid integer overflow of signed numbers. If you expect the input to fit inside an unsigned 32 variable but not a signed one, you should be using `strtoul` etc functions and after that convert to the signed type.

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors inside this code.

The main issue in the first line is that you cannot cast a long int to an `int16_t` because `int16_t` is smaller in size than a `long int`. 
In addition you should use the `PRId16` specifier to print an `int16_t`.

The second line results in printing `LONG_MAX` as `0xFFFFF123` is out of range for a long int.

The third line has the same issue as the second, `FFFFFFFFFFFFF123` is even more out of range and casting it to a 64bit values not help.
In addition you need to print it with `%lld` or `PRId64` as Michael already stated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the maximum input for `strtol`is 0x7fffffff (or LONG_MAX). If the number to convert is out of range, `errno` is set and the result is `LONG_MAX` or `LONG_MIN`, see the [strtol documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) for more details.

Illustration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {

  int x = strtol("7f000000", NULL, 16);  // in range
  printf ("x = %d, errno = %d\n", errno);

  x = strtol("F0000000", NULL, 16);      // out of range
  printf ("x = %d, errno = %d\n", errno);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x = 2130706432, errno = 0
x = 2147483647, errno = 34
```